# NextJS does not load on iPhone using cellular connection

Tags: ios, reactjs, docker, nginx, next.js

I have built a production NextJS (v11.1) web-app with React (v17.0.2). I then compiled a Docker (v20.10.8) image on an Apple MacBook Air M1 using buildx to ensure compatibility with amd64 processors. I then deployed the image to AWS EC2 on Ubuntu 20.04 with an x86_64 processor. I am also using Node (v14.17.5), Apollo Client (v3.4.8), GraphQL (v15.5.1) and finally NGINX (v1.18.0) as a reverse proxy server.

The image successfully deployed. I can visit my webpage on a laptop (macOS Big Sur v11.5.2) over WiFi, on an iPhone (iOS v14.7.1) over WiFi, and on Android phones with either WiFi or a cellular connection. Unfortunately, I cannot visit my webpage on an iPhone over cellular connection. I was hoping that connecting to the webpage on my laptop, but through the iPhone's hotspot feature would provide more insight. However, the page failed to load and I still didn't see much useful information.

To the best of my knowledge each technology is using the latest, stable version. Does anyone know why a NextJS web-app would fail to load specifically on an iPhone using a cellular connection? Or even have additional insight into how I might debug this issue?

Comment: Is your android phone using the same cellular provider as your iPhone? If you hotspot the iPhone to the Android phone does it work?  Have you used utilities like ping and traceroute to verify connection from your laptop (through the iPhone hotspot) to your server?  Have you checked your server for iPv6 support?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The problem was that I had disabled NGINX support for IPv6, while I had forgotten to disable IPv6 support in Route 53 / AWS. I chose to disable IPv6 and the issue is resolved.